# See which words from list are in each item using str.contians

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I am trying extract which words were found in a `str.contains()` search as seen in the image below (but using pandas and `str.contains`, not VBA). I'm trying to recreate the output in the VBA result column.

[image]

Here's what I was using to simply show me if the words were found in each comment:

```
searchfor = list(terms['term'])
found = [reviews['review_trimmed'].str.contains(x) for x in searchfor]
result = pd.DataFrame(found)
```

This is great in that I know which comments have the terms I'm looking for, but I don't know which terms it found for each. I would like my answer to utilize `str.contains` for consistency.

Comment: Is `Series.str.contains` *really* a requirement? I think the correct tool for this job is the closely related `Series.str.extractall` where you would create a search pattern by `'|'.join`ing the "Words to look for".

Comment: @ALollz I just need it to be consistent with the output that I got in the code with str.contains

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using Grzegorz Skibinski's Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "review_trimmed": [
        "dog and cat",
        "Cat chases mouse",
        "horrible thing",
        "noodle soup",
        "chilli",
        "pizza is Good"
    ]
})

searchfor = "yes cat Dog soup good bad horrible".split()

df

     review_trimmed
0       dog and cat
1  Cat chases mouse
2    horrible thing
3       noodle soup
4            chilli
5     pizza is Good
```

## _______________________________________________________

#### Solution (`pandas.Series.str.findall`)

- Use `'|'.join` to combine all items searched for into a regex string that searches for any of the items.
- Use `flag=2` which implies `IGNORECASE`

---

```
df.review_trimmed.str.findall('|'.join(searchfor), 2)

0    [dog, cat]
1         [Cat]
2    [horrible]
3        [soup]
4            []
5        [Good]
Name: review_trimmed, dtype: object
```

We can `join` them with `';'` like so:

```
df.review_trimmed.str.findall('|'.join(searchfor), 2).str.join(';')

0     dog;cat
1         Cat
2    horrible
3        soup
4            
5        Good
Name: review_trimmed, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `numpy`:

```py
searchfor=[wrd.lower() for wrd in searchfor]
searchfor=set(searchfor)
df["found"]=np.bitwise_and(df["review_trimmed"].str.lower().str.split("[^\w+]").map(set), searchfor)
```

To show the output I used dummy data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"review_trimmed": ["dog and cat", "Cat chases mouse", "horrible thing", "noodle soup", "chilli", "pizza is Good"]})

searchfor="yes cat Dog soup good bad horrible".split(" ")

searchfor=[wrd.lower() for wrd in searchfor]
searchfor=set(searchfor)
df["found"]=np.bitwise_and(df["review_trimmed"].str.lower().str.split("[^\w+]").map(set), searchfor)
print(searchfor)
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```py
#searchfor:
{'cat', 'good', 'yes', 'dog', 'bad', 'horrible', 'soup'}

#df:
     review_trimmed       found
0       dog and cat  {cat, dog}
1  Cat chases mouse       {cat}
2    horrible thing  {horrible}
3       noodle soup      {soup}
4            chilli          {}
5     pizza is Good      {good}
```

**Edit**

IIUC - just add `.str.join(";")`

```
searchfor=[wrd.lower() for wrd in searchfor]
searchfor=set(searchfor)
df["found"]=np.bitwise_and(df["review_trimmed"].str.lower().str.split("[^\w+]").map(set), searchfor).str.join(";")
print(searchfor)
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```py
{'dog', 'soup', 'cat', 'bad', 'good', 'yes', 'horrible'}
     review_trimmed     found
0       dog and cat   dog;cat
1  Cat chases mouse       cat
2    horrible thing  horrible
3       noodle soup      soup
4            chilli
5     pizza is Good      good
```

Comment: The output of this is not consistent with my original code. It shows empty {} when my result dataframe showed True

Answer (score 0):

I tried this through  for loop,

```
import pandas as pd

words_to_look=['Yes','No']
sentences=['He knows Yes No Yes','No He dont know','He Know' ]

df=pd.DataFrame(sentences,columns=['Comments_to_look'])

string=""
final_list=[]

for item in df['Comments_to_look']:
    items=set(item.split())
    for item2 in items:
        for item3 in words_to_look:
            if item2==item3:
                string=item3+" "+string
                break
    final_list.append(string)
    string=""

df['words occured']=final_list
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Comments_to_look      words occured
0   He knows Yes No Yes   Yes No
1   No He dont know       No
2   He Know
```